# VideoPlayer view prevents SwiftUI Navigation Bar from hiding

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink, avkit

The problem occurs when I put `VideoPlayer` view inside `NavigationView`'s parent view or child view. In this example the child view will show navigation bar:

```
struct ParentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Text("Parent View")

        NavigationLink(destination: ChildView().navigationBarHidden(true)) {
          Text("Child View")
        }
      }
      .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Child View")
      VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer())
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue. Not sure what's causing it but I ended up replacing the `VideoPlayer` with a custom one. That removed the space on top.

```
  struct CustomPlayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  let src: String

  func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: src)!)
    controller.player = player
    player.play()
    return controller
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomPlayer>) { }
}
```

And in your view where you want to use it, do:

```
CustomPlayer(src: "<the source to the video>")
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution works. But I got another problem with CustomPlayer - it doesn't work with dynamic source. I tried to pass AVPlayer instead of src, but still looking for solution to make it update the source on change.

Answer (score 2):

if you want a custom player with the same initializer as the native one and that updates along with the current state of the application:

```swift
struct CustomPlayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let player: AVPlayer

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomPlayer>) {
        uiViewController.player = player
    }
}
```

note that on `updateUIViewController(_: context:)` you should update the view with every variable you declared and expect to update